# How to erase blender gltf object animations

Tags: animation, export, gltf, three.js

I'm creating object animations in Blender and exporting the objects as gltf models before importing them with @react-three/drei to my development react project. There is however a big deviation between the number of animations I create in Blender and the number of animations loaded to the gltf object as I access it through threejs.

Below are two screenshots, the first displaying the four animations I created in Blender, and the other showing the myriad of other animations that latched onto the object as I exported it and opened it in the browser inspector tool.

How do I erase these animations in blender before export?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you delete all animations in your file and disable animation export and still get animations in your gltf, there is a problem. Could you share your blend file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to insert the link please? So that we can check what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Each and all animations are contained in "actions". To delete all animations easily from one place, you can delete all actions from the outliner.

First set your Outliner display mode to Blender File:

[image]

Then, hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and click the first and last element in the actions' category to select them all. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Delete.

Comment: under the action tab only the animations that is already defined appears, i.e., the spiral, cube, plane, cylinder etc. animations are not accessible through this tab

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. All animations in Blender are stored in Actions afaik. Have you tried disabling animation export in the gltf export options?

Comment: Or if there is only one you want to export, disable "export all armature actions" i guess

Comment: neither of these two options helped. In my perception it must be the auto keyframe function that creates all these unwanted animations and this is annoying af